# Sum over partitions of a number

Tags: summation, partitions

I know only some basics about mathematica. However I need to write down the following sum:

$\sum_{\{m_k\}_N}\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{m_k}[T_k(Z(\tau))]^{m_k}$.

Where $\{m_k\}_N$ denotes partitions of $N$ i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^Nkm_k=N$. The argument in brackets [..] is the Hecke Operator, for now not that important. My problem is more that I do not know how to write the sum over partitions. The Hecke Operator I would then just insert and I think this would not be the most difficult part.

I know that usually I should write some code expressing my trials however I really have no idea how to handle the problem. Could someone please help me.

Comment: Could you explain, maybe with a simple by-hand example, how do you want to sum over partitions? As `IntegerPartitions[4]` gives a set of sets, so I don't fully understand.

Comment: Sure: Take the example $N=3$. Then we have: $1\cdot 3=3 \Rightarrow m_1=3$, $1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 2 = 3 \Rightarrow m_1=1, m_2=1$, $3\cdot 1=3 \Rightarrow m_3=1$. Thus the above sum up to prefactors is: $(T_1Z(\tau))^3 + T_1Z(\tau)T_2Z(\tau) + T_3Z(\tau)$.

Comment: This is not exactly what IntegerPartitions does.

Comment: Look up `FrobeniusSolve[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Tally` transforms `IntegerPartitions` into what you need:

```
Total[Times @@@ Map[Last[#]^-1 T[First[#], Z[\[Tau]]]^Last[#] &,
                     Tally /@ IntegerPartitions[3], {2}], {1, 2}]
```

Comment: This is my outcome: $T[1, Z[\[Tau]]] + T[1, Z[\[Tau]]]^3 + T[2, Z[\[Tau]]] + 
 T[3, Z[\[Tau]]]$. It is not exactly what I want. But I think I get what you mean.

Comment: or actually I do not get it, could you please explain your code?

Comment: what is the meaning of the $\{1,2\}$ at the end?

Comment: @user404302 I edited so that numbers from same partition are multiplied, and added the division by $m_k$. `Total[#,{1,2}]&` sums the numbers of a matrix or non-rectangular 2d array (as in this case)

Comment: So now I get it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments, using `FrobeniusSolve[]` in `Sum[]` is the most convenient way to implement the sum:

```
With[{n = 3}, 
     Sum[Product[If[m[[k]] != 0, tz[k]^m[[k]]/m[[k]], 1], {k, Length[m]}],
         {m, FrobeniusSolve[Range[n], n]}]]
   tz[1]^3/3 + tz[1] tz[2] + tz[3]
```